# How do I get a *mut c_char from a Str?

Tags: rust

To be able to use C library, I need to give a `*mut c_char` parameter to a function. But I don't find a way to have it from a `str`.

I converted my str to a [CString](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ffi/struct.CString.html), that's ok, but there's no more way from CString to get a `*mut c_char` in the nightly build. I found that in 0.12.0 there was a [method](http://doc.rust-lang.org/0.12.0/std/c_str/struct.CString.html#method.as_mut_ptr), but now, what is the process to get that `*mut c_char`?

Comment: Which kind of string do you have, a `&str` or a `String`?

Comment: Please include the signature of the C function, as it will contain details about how the method is supposed to be called. Specifically, I'm curious how the function knows how much space there is in the string so it doesn't extend past allocated memory.

Comment: Ideally `CString` would have `DerefMut` implementation with `Output = [c_char]`, so it would be possible to obtain `*mut c_char` just with `c_str.as_mut_ptr()`. But I think that the reason there is no such implementation is that it could break `CString` guarantee that it does not contain zeros inside: `c_str[2] = 0` would be possible in that case. So, I think, your `Vec`-based solution is fine; just don't forget to push a zero byte at the end if your C API needs a zero-terminated string.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
let bytes = String::from_str("Test").into_bytes() + b"\0";
let cchars = bytes.map_in_place(|b| b as c_char);
let name: *mut c_char = cchars.as_mut_ptr();
```

The basic idea is the same as yours but there is no need to slice the `Vec` explicitly; also a zero byte is appended to the buffer. See also my comment to the question.

Comment: Thank you, in fact, one less function to call that's always better ^^

Comment: This answer doesn't work in 2021 unfortunately :(

Answer (score 4):

Five years later and none of these solutions are working (for me, at least).

A slightly modified version of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28097311/12344841):

```rust
let string: &str = "Hello, world!";
let bytes: Vec<u8> = String::from(string).into_bytes();
let mut c_chars: Vec<i8> = bytes.iter().map(| c | *c as i8).collect::<Vec<i8>>();

c_chars.push(0); // null terminator

let ptr: *mut c_char = c_chars.as_mut_ptr();
```

Comment: Those first two lines can be simplified to `let bytes = b"Hello, world!".to_vec();`

Answer (score 2):

Now (2022), `into_raw()` works well for me, for example:

```rust
use std::ffi::CString;
use std::os::raw::c_char;
fn main() {    
  let c_string = CString::new("Hello!").expect("CString::new failed");
  let raw: *mut c_char = c_string.into_raw();
}
```

Check https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ffi/struct.CString.html#method.into_raw for more information.

Comment: You need to be careful with into_raw because it will cause a memory leak, unless you convert it back into a CString

Answer (score 1):

Look at [this piece of documentation](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/slice/trait.SliceExt.html#tymethod.as_mut_ptr), the `fn as_mut_ptr()` has been moved to the *slice* part of the API. So you need a mutable slice of type `&mut [c_char]`. And AFAIK you cannot get that from a `CString`, those would be read-only.

Instead you can use a `mut Vec<c_char>`:

```
let mut x : Vec<c_char> = ...;
let slice = x.as_mut_slice();
let ptr = slice.as_mut_ptr();
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to rodrigo's post, I found a way (very dirty, but it works) to solve my problem. Here is the code :

```
let mut string = std::string::String::from_str("Test");
let bytes = string.into_bytes();
let mut cchar : Vec<c_char> = bytes.map_in_place(|w| w as c_char);
let slice = cchar.as_mut_slice();
let name: *mut c_char = slice.as_mut_ptr();
```

A bit complex in my opinion

Comment: Nice, but I think you can omit the `map_in_place`. Maybe the compiler is able to optimize out that code, because a `u8` and a `c_char` (aka `i8`) are guaranteed to be bit-identical, IIANM.

Comment: No, it does not compile without the map_in_place ;)

Comment: What I mean is that you can declare `name : *mut u8` and change the API import code accordingly and all should just work. Or maybe you could `transmute()` it, but I don't know the exact rules.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to

```rust
let mut hello =   b"Hello World\0".to_vec().as_mut_ptr() as *mut i8;
```